# NoMethodError when calling JJWT from Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jjwt

I'm working on a small Spring Boot application in Kotlin and now I want to secure it using JJWT. Roughly speaking, I am translating this tutorial to my use case: https://jakublesko.com/spring-security-with-jwt/

In the project I have this AuthenticationFilter:

```
class JwtAuthenticationFilter(val authManager: AuthenticationManager) : UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {

    // other stuff omitted for brevity

    override fun successfulAuthentication(request: HttpServletRequest?, response: HttpServletResponse?, chain: FilterChain?, authResult: Authentication?) {
        val user = authResult?.principal as User

        val roles = user.authorities
                .stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)

        val signingKey = JWT_SECRET.toByteArray()

        val token = Jwts.builder()
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(signingKey))
                .setHeaderParam("typ", TOKEN_TYPE) // validate that "typ" does not actually mean "type"
                .setIssuer(TOKEN_ISSUER)
                .setAudience(TOKEN_AUDIENCE)
                .setSubject(user.username)
                .setExpiration(Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 864000000))
                .claim("rol", roles)
                .compact()

        response?.addHeader(TOKEN_HEADER, TOKEN_PREFIX + token)
    }
}
```

When I post to the authentication URL that is supposed to issue a token though, I receive:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm.getMinKeyLength()I
    at io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Keys.java:69) ~[jjwt-api-0.10.7.jar:na]`

I can debug into the `successfulAuthentication` method and see that it is called with reasonable parameters. What catches my eye is the "I" after the parenthesis at the end of the `getMinKeyLength()I`. My googling skills apparently do not suffice to find a reason why it is there, but I strongly suspect it is related to reflection & calling Java libs from Kotlin code.

Is anyone around who can tell me how to fix this? I have run out of guesses.

Comment: JJWT 0.10.7's Keys.java line 69 is just a standard (non-reflective) Java method call: https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/blob/0.10.7/api/src/main/java/io/jsonwebtoken/security/Keys.java. I've no idea why Kotlin would have a problem with it - I wish I knew myself :/

Comment: were you able to resolve this? Any luck?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. :/

Comment: I wonder what it could be - it's a normal Java call, no reflection.  :/

Comment: This looks like a dependency version issue. Notice that your 'signwith()' has a different parameter order than your example. Try it again using the same versions in that example - '0.10.5'.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon the same issue. The reason for this is most probably a dependency conflict. Check if you have any other dependency using jjwt. For us it was `com.twilio.sdk`.

You can do it using

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

After you've identified the conflicting dependency you can either match your jjwt version or exclude it from the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

to run java code from Kotlin, please put the java sources under the folder

main/java

Also, your kotlin sources are located under main/kotlin